# How to MASK(obfuscate) certain column in SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to give database access to someone else, but I want to hide sensitive data like credit card numbers and email addresses. The Masked function does not work in SQL server 2012.

What is the best way of solving this problem?

Comment: Masking isn't a security feature. First of all, there's no reason a new account should have access to *every* database object. You can give permissions to only specific tables, or views that return *only* the fields that account is allowed to read. You can [use column-level permissions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/) to prevent the user from accessing sensitive fields even in the table he/she has read access

Comment: I have to mask credit card number Like this 7588-XXXX-XXXX-XX96  when i give access to other person

Comment: You don't need to give access to the column at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to use new stuff like [dynamic data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2017) or [row level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017) to restrict access to certain fields or rows, so you can go to the old way.

Create views and expose only the fields you need to show. Grant access to these views only.

Don't be sad about the dynamic data masking. It is not a security feature and there various techniques to expose the information.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_SenstiveData]
AS
SELECT [UserID]
      ,'XXXXXXXX' AS [UserName]
      ,LEFT([SocialID], 4) + '-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-' + RIGHT([SocialID], 3) AS [SocialID]
FROM [dbo].[Users]
```

Comment: I want to show the data but it should be masked like this credit card number: 8888-XXXX-XXXX-XX65

Comment: @vickykumar You can do this exactly in the view. You can apply your own scalar function for formatting the data, or you can add hard-coded string, or you can skip the column. Let, me know if you need help for writing such function.

Comment: how can I achieve this I have 3 tables with contains sensitive information.
 Can you give me any references?

Comment: @vickykumar just write the obfuscation code in the view's SQL query. You don't need any references for this, just use `LEFT(5)`, `RIGHT(2)` and other substring functions to return what you want, concatenate them with `X` characters

Comment: My sir said we cannot use the view. we need to mask the column in the original table only so that other person accessing the database cannot see the sensitive data and we need to unmask the data for some other users. how can I achieve that?

Comment: How you are going to give this user access to the database?

Comment: I'm going to give him username and password to SQL server database.

Comment: And you are not allowed to create views?

Comment: No he said creating a view is bad idea

Comment: Then you need to deny the access to his account to all tables containing sensitive data.